# Is it possible to randomize the order in which Spock tests are executed?

Tags: groovy, spock

it seems that spock tests are executed in the same order, most of the time.

Is it possible to set some option to execute them in a random order?

**Update:** as tim_yates commented "tests should be isolated, and order shouldn't matter", I think I should explain why I would like to have this feature...

We had a code retreat where we tried to just tried to turn the tests green. So we implemented a state in the class under test which then would be used to return the corerct result for all tests.

To avoid such evil coding, I thought it would be great to execute tests in random order :-)

Comment: Do you mean test classes or the tests in a class?

Comment: The tests (features) in a class aka in a spec

Answer (score 6):

> *After [Leonard Brünings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145769/leonard-br%C3%BCnings) suggestion, I've replaced the solution based on extending `Sputnik` with using annotation-driven extension.*

You can create your own Spock extension that randomizes features. Consider the following example.

```groovy
package com.github.wololock

import spock.lang.Specification

@RandomizedOrder
class RandomSpockSpec extends Specification {

    def "test 1"() {
        when:
        def number = 1

        then:
        println "[${new Date().format("HH:mm:ss.SSS")}] number ${number}"
    }

    def "test 2"() {
        when:
        def number = 2

        then:
        println "[${new Date().format("HH:mm:ss.SSS")}] number ${number}"
    }

    def "test 3"() {
        when:
        def number = 3

        then:
        println "[${new Date().format("HH:mm:ss.SSS")}] number ${number}"
    }

    def "test 4"() {
        when:
        def number = 4

        then:
        println "[${new Date().format("HH:mm:ss.SSS")}] number ${number}"
    }

    def "test 5"() {
        when:
        def number = 5

        then:
        println "[${new Date().format("HH:mm:ss.SSS")}] number ${number}"
    }
}
```

<sup>*[src/test/groovy/com/github/wololock/RandomSpockSpec.groovy](https://github.com/wololock/spock-random-order-demo/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/github/wololock/RandomSpockSpec.groovy)*</sup>

This specification contains 5 features that prints numbers to the console. We use a custom `@RandomizeOrder` annotation (see [*"Annotation-Driven Local Extension"*](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/extensions.html#_annotation_driven_local_extensions) docs). Firstly, we create an annotation class.

```groovy
package com.github.wololock

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecInfo

final class RandomizedOrderExtension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<RandomizedOrder> {

    public static final String SPOCK_RANDOM_ORDER_SEED = "spock.random.order.seed"

    private static final long seed = System.getProperty(SPOCK_RANDOM_ORDER_SEED)?.toLong() ?: System.nanoTime()

    static {
        println "Random seed used: ${seed}\nYou can re-run the test with predefined seed by passing -D${SPOCK_RANDOM_ORDER_SEED}=${seed}\n\n"
    }

    @Override
    void visitSpecAnnotation(RandomizedOrder annotation, SpecInfo spec) {
        final Random random = new Random(seed)

        final List<Integer> order = (0..(spec.features.size())) as ArrayList

        Collections.shuffle(order, random)

        spec.features.each { feature ->
            feature.executionOrder = order.pop()
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>*[src/test/groovy/com/github/wololock/RandomizedOrderExtension.groovy](https://github.com/wololock/spock-random-order-demo/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/github/wololock/RandomizedOrderExtension.groovy)*</sup>

This extension does one thing - in the `visitSpec` visitor method we assign a random execution order to all feature methods. It supports predefined seed, so whenever you want to re-create a specific order, you can read the seed value from the console and you can pass it in the next run. For instance, the following parameter added `-Dspock.random.order.seed=1618636504276` will shuffle features using predefined seed.

When we run the test annotated with `@RandomizedOrder` we will see methods in the order different than the declaration order.

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that tests should be isolated, and order shouldn't matter. Except for @Stepwise tests. I guess this could be handy for checking that a service isn't carrying unknown state that causes issues though 

Comment: I agree. I would be OK if the default order was random, and only @Stepwise guaranteed declaration order (and single failure break).

Comment: Please don't use a custom runner or extend Sputnik, Spock already has extension points that allow the ordering of Features.

Comment: Thanks, @LeonardBrünings for pointing that out. Your comment and suggestion is valid and makes much more sense.

Comment: Whichever answers your question better, I think :)

Comment: Since you already wrote the extension, you might want to log the randomization seed and give a way to supply a fixed seed to reproduce errors.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Great idea, thanks! It makes the extension even more useful. I've updated the answer. Thanks! :+1:

Comment: @SzymonStepniak nitpicking: you could use java.lang.Long#getLong(java.lang.String, long) instead. 

The other problem I see is that you will get a different order depending whether you run one test class or more than one test class, since you use a shared random. This makes it more complicated to recreate the failure, since you need to rerun all tests, instead of just the failing class.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Local random is also problematic in this case. Imagine running e.g. 10 tests and every spec uses a different seed. Now, the 3 specs failed and you end up with 3 different seeds. You can't re-run all 3 specs at once in this case, you can only re-run them one-by-one, changing the seed every time. My first approach was the local random, but then I realized its limitations. I would say that it is up to the end user if he/she wants to use a local or static random. I would recommend a static one, however, to avoid the problem with re-running multiple failing tests.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I meant every test class should use the same seed but reinitialize the Random. Just do `new Random(seed)` inside the `visitSpecAnnotation`.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Ahhh, you're right. That's a really good point. Using the same random object across all tests without re-initializing with the same seed puts us in the non-deterministic corner. Thanks for paying attention to that detail.

Answer (score 5):

As you only want to randomize the order of tests inside a class, then this can be achieved with an extension. Take a look at [StepwiseExtension](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/extension/builtin/StepwiseExtension.java)

```
private void sortFeaturesInDeclarationOrder(SpecInfo spec) {
    for (FeatureInfo feature : spec.getFeatures())
      feature.setExecutionOrder(feature.getDeclarationOrder());
 }
```

You can simply randomize the execution order, in you own extension. Depending on whether you want it only selectively or for all your tests. You can create either an `AnnotationDrivenExtension` or a `IGlobalExtension` see the [docs](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_writing_custom_extensions) on how that works.